# ¿Cómo leer en tiempo real un puerto serie RS232?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyserial

Estoy intentando armar una interfaz en Python 2.7 a través de PyQt en la que despliega en tiempo real una serie de muestras que llegan por RS232. Una versión antigua del programa en visual basic imprime en tiempo real las muestra a través de la ejecución de "eventos".

¿Existe alguna forma de generar una función que se ejecute cuando llega un dato por el puerto?

Buscaría algo de la siguiente forma:

```python
class MyWindowClass(QtGui.QMainWindow, form_class):
 def __init__(self, parent=None):
    self.serialCOM = serial.Serial("COM2", baudrate=9600, timeout = 00)
    ... 
  self.connect(EVENTO DE PUERTO SERIE,self.Serial_event) #En esta parte es donde no logro llegar a nada

 def Serial_event(self):
    paquete = self.serialCOM.read()
    self.window_text.insertPlainText(paquete)
```

Answer (score 1):

Crea una hebra que se quede constantemente leyendo.

```
s = serial.Serial()
while True:
   rx = s.read()
   if rx:
      print 'your-event', rx
   else:
      rx = None
```